# How to use min, max validation in template form angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I tried to use min validation in template form, but it didn't work. How to use it in template form? Thanks for your help.

```
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="srvc_sub_cnt{{i}}" 
          [ngModel]="s?.srvc_sub_cnt" (ngModelChange)="s?.srvc_sub_cnt?
               s.srvc_sub_cnt=$event:null"
          required #srvc_sub_cnt="ngModel" pattern="^[0-9]+$" min="1">

        <div class="cell table-info" *ngIf="srvc_sub_cnt.errors?.min" class="form_error">
                    Service Subscribers must be greater than 0.
                  </div>
```

Comment: wasn't my answer helpful ? :p

Comment: The easiest way could be *ngIf="s?.srvc_sub_cnt<1"

Comment: marked as duplicate, ping me if you disagree, but the dupe gives you the information you need. Even though that is talking about angular 2 final, things have not changed, in template driven form min/max does not work. Like in dupe, now min/max is supported in reactive forms, so you can consider going that route :)

Comment: Thank you, AJT. I found the link you provided very useful.

Answer (score 5):

To use `min/max validations` on input of type `number` you'll have to create `Custom Validators`

You can use [this](https://github.com/yuyang041060120/ng2-validation) library. It implements a lot of `custom validator`

Including above library in your code, you can use `min/max` like

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="model.field" name="field" #field="ngModel" [min]="10"/>
<p *ngIf="field.errors?.min">error message</p>
```

Comment: thank you. I found the answer in the above link. I will create a custom validator.

Comment: so give it a upvote and accept :p

Comment: Hi Usman, thank you so much for the help. I found answer from dupe link. Thanks anyway.